# How can I transform a time signal into a third octave spectrum?

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum

I try to make a third-octave spectrum from a time signal and I have some troubles with the algorithm. I'm not an expert in signal processing so I don't know what is wrong.

Here what my algorithm looks like :

Time signal -> Z transform of the signal -> First octave band filtering -> Quadratic sum of the result's values => First octave band value.
Under factor 2 sampling ->Z transform of the signal -> Second octave band filtering -> Quadratic sum of the result's values =>Second octave band.

Now I have this, I try to test it on Matlab with a time signal about 2 millions points.

I have this code to calculate all the octave's bands :

```
    fc = fMin*2.^((0:bmax)*bw);             %Center frequencies.
    fl = fc*2^(-bw/2);                      %Lower cutoffs.
    fu = fc*2^(+bw/2);                      %Upper cutoffs.
```

And this one to calculate the Z transform of the time signal :

```
    x = [1 2 3];
    syms z;
    d = z.^(-1*(0:numel(x)-1));
    zTransform = sum(x.*d)
```

My main problem is, I'm not completely sure that my algorithm is right and if it is, how can I filter the z transform equation that the code above gives me with each third-octave band filters?

Thanks in advance, it's been a while I'm on this problem.

Comment: How is that different from the question you asked [before](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/49253/create-a-third-octave-spectrum-from-a-time-signal/49255#49255)?

Answer (score 1):

maybe either the bandpass filters or the peaking EQ filters in the [audio EQ cookbook](https://www.w3.org/TR/audio-eq-cookbook/) can help.  bandwidth is defined in octaves in that.  the output, $y$, of each 1/3 octave BPF filter should be squared and low-pass filtered to get the mean square, $\overline{y^2}$.  and then

$$dB = 10 \log_{10}\Big(\,\overline{y^2}\,\Big)$$

is applied to that to get dB.

are you planning on doing this to the whole audible spectrum?  31 bands?

Comment: Yes, I would like to filter the signal from 10Hz to 10kHz (maybe 20kHz later). In fact, the z transform calcul gives me an equation in output. I don't know what can I do with it. Is there not a better way, have a table in output ? It will be easy after to filter this

Comment: if you have something that works, go with it.  if it doesn't work or you don't understand what is necessary to make it work, you might need to try something else.  i wouldn't bother with the bottom octave from 10 to 20 Hz.  you should consider what the conventional 31 band frequencies are

Comment: Actually, this calcul works with few points. But when I try to insert a table with 2 millions points, my computer is out of memory... 
To filter a z transform spectrum, I need to have a table of datas in output, no ?

Comment: What do you mean by "You should consider what the conventional 31 band frequencies are" ?

Comment: you're doing a 1/3 Octave spectrum analyzer over 10 octaves, right?  including both [fenceposts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error), that is 30+1 bands.  they have standard frequencies: ...100, 125, 160, 200, 250, 320, 400, 500, 630, 800, 1000, 1250, ...

Comment: i guess [these guys are saying it's 315 Hz](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/octave-bands-frequency-limits-d_1602.html) rather than 320 Hz.  it's not the decision i would make, but i guess it's okay.